# django LEFT JOIN on not native database

Tags: django

I have database and I will make integration with django, I have  already models and I will execute some JOIN LEFT query django way.

Here my models:

```
class Platforms(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'lu_platform'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Sources(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'lu_sourcetype'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Events(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    platform_id = models.IntegerField()
    host_id = models.IntegerField()
    sourcetype_id = models.IntegerField()
    event_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=2048)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'event'
```

And here is my query, how I can execute following query in django way?

```
SELECT event_datetime, lu_platform.name, host.name, data 
FROM event 
LEFT JOIN lu_platform ON event.platform_id = lu_platform.id 
LEFT JOIN host ON event.host_id = host.id
WHERE event.platform_id = 8 
AND event_datetime BETWEEN '2013-11-23' AND '2013-12-28' 
AND event.sourcetype_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the models need to be changed to mention the ForeignKey relationships. Next, the `id` fields are automatically added by Django and are redundant. Finally, it is recommended to use singular names for models. I would design them in this way:

```
class Platform(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'lu_platform'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Source(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'lu_sourcetype'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Event(models.Model):
    host_id = models.IntegerField()
    platform = models.ForeignKey(Platform)
    sourcetype = models.ForeignKey(Source)
    event_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=2048)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'event'
```

Finally, the query would look something like this:

```
Event.objects.filter(platform__id=8, event_datetime__range=["2013-11-23", "2013-12-28"],sourcetype_id=1).values(
      "event_datetime", "platform__name", "host_id", "data")
```

I am on a train so I cannot verify the above code but it should work.

Comment: Thank you @arocks, your answer solved my issue, I adjusted the models and this are my query:
`data = Event.objects.filter(platform_id__in=[1,7,8],
                                 sourcetype_id__in=[1],
                                 event_datetime__range=(t_start, t_end)).values(
                                     "event_datetime",
                                     "platform__name",
                                     "host__name", "data")`